# Python OrderedDict iterable over int

Tags: python, dictionary, int

I'm learning about dictionaries and I wrote a small bit of code and built it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = OrderedDict([('a',0),('b',9),('c',8),('d',7),('e',6)])
d2 = OrderedDict([(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)])
```

I get the following error:

```
d2 = OrderedDict([(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't understand why it isn't iterable? And what has `'int'` got to do with the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `(1)` is the integer 1. OrderedDict expects two-element iterables (with a key and a value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) you need to provide `key-value` pairs to `OrderedDict`.

At its core, `OrderedDict` is a `dictionary` and thus needs a `value` to store at a `key`.
Passing it (1) is wrong because:

```
>>a = (1)
>>type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

So, (1) is not a tuple but an `integer` object.

Answer (score 3):

`OrderedDict`s (or any sub-class of `dict` for that matter) are a set of key-value pairs.

```
>>> d1 = OrderedDict([('a',0),('b',9),('c',8),('d',7),('e',6)])
>>> d1['b']
9
```

The following statement does not provide any such pairs.

```
d2 = OrderedDict([(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)])
```

Also note that
`(1)` is an `int`.
`(1,)` is a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

The list elements should be a tuple of 2 items (one key and another value).

`(1)` becomes `1` an `int`. So what python is doing is it is trying to split it into key-value pair. So you get that error.